# How to Show a Collection of Object to Be Inserted Into the Database

Tags: django

I would like to build a Django app that allows searching for a movie on TagChimp using their API and then storing the right movie in the web app's database. Here is how I think it could work:

[image: Information flow of movie saving]
This is what my small app should do:

1. let the user enter a search term for a movie title
2. display certain attributes of found movies like title, year and picture, but keep the other attributes around
3. wait for the user to pick the right movie he was looking for and insert all of the meta data into the database using a movie model

I programmed a view which is passed a movie title and it uses a helper object to fetch the movies from TagChimp. It parses the XML and it creates an array of dictionaries which hold all the interesting meta data and displays the search results on the page.

The next step would be that the user picks the right movie and then it is converted to a model object and inserted into the db.

I am new to django so I am not really sure how to store this temporary search result, of which the user picks the right one. Is there a way to temporary create model objects and just save the one the user picks? Would this be implemented all in one view or would you create separate views for each step of the process (entering search term - displaying results and letting the user pick the right one - inserting the movie into the db)?

As Bialeki points out I have two possible ways of dealing with that problem:

1. save the TagChimpID of each record as a hidden value in the form in step 2 and starting a second request searching just for the selected TagChimpID or
2. somehow keep the fetched movies around in step 2 so I can insert the movie right away

The first option is maybe easier to implement, but needs two request to the external data source, whereas the second option could be faster as just one external request is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, if you create a Django model, it doesn't persist it to the database. So you could do something like:

```
def view(request):

  results = search(request.GET['query'])
  possible_movies = []

  for result in results:
    possible_movies.append(
      Movie(title=result.title, year=result.year, picture=picture)
    )

  return render_to_response('view.html', possible_movies=possible_movies)
```

Then in your view, when someone selects one, you'll need to pass back either an ID to find those pieces of data again or pass back the title, year, picture, etc. Pretty straightforward if someone submits a form to continue and you include them as hidden fields.

The key is that to persist something to the database, you must call `save`.

```
movie = Movie(title=title, year=year, picture=picture, **other_data)

# Movie is not currently saved.
print movie.id
# prints 'None'


movie.save()

# Movie is saved

print movie.id
# prints 123
```

Comment: So is it correct that I have to include all attributes of the possible movies, which are not shown in the selection list, as hidden fields in the form? So if I get the form's data after the user has selected a movie, I have to again generate a movie object and then save it?

Comment: That's how I would do it. You could use Django sessions and stash the model in there, but then your pages aren't stateless. Another thing to consider is if there's an ID generated by the place you're initially querying for movies (seems that way from your description of the problem), you could just store that and then look up that ID when it's time to save.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the question with a picture to illustrate the data flow. I think it might be easy in this case to get away with just storing the record IDs of TagChimp. However if there were no such ID I think I would have to introduce sessions. Now I have to get pagination running if the user gets too many results for the query.